# Can't see my app icon on windows store

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I upload my application to the store and passed the certification process and its already in the store(hidden because is a enterprise app).

When i search the app in the store its there but i cannot see the icon of the app, just the preview images. Where can i update that information? I also would like to update the preview images but i cant find it neither in the dashboard.

In case you need it, here its the `AppManifest.xml`

```
  <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
    <Identity Name="...."
              Version="1.0.0.0"
              Publisher="...." />

    <Properties>
      <DisplayName>MyAppName:D</DisplayName>
      <PublisherDisplayName>meOfCourse</PublisherDisplayName>
      <Logo>company_logo.png</Logo>
    </Properties>
    <Prerequisites>
      <OSMinVersion>8.0</OSMinVersion>
      <OSMaxVersionTested>8.0</OSMaxVersionTested>
    </Prerequisites>
    <Resources>
      <Resource Language="en-us" />
      <Resource Language="es-do" />
    </Resources>
    <Applications>
      <Application Id="app" StartPage="Authentication.xaml">
        <VisualElements DisplayName="appName" Description="asdf"
             Logo="company_logo.png" SmallLogo="company_logo.png"
             ForegroundText="dark" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
          <SplashScreen Image="company_logo_splash.png" />
        </VisualElements>
      </Application>
    </Applications>
  </Package>
```

**Note**: I'm sorry if this not the correct place to ask this. If is not, please guide me where should I.

Comment: in the dev center create a new release for your app.   you can update the images and submit it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the images and submit the application again. Just verify that your icon images are perfect match to the required dimensions. Also, below the icon images while submitting, there is a check mark to "generate icons for other resolutions" which might be necessary if you are not submitting all the icons and just for the highest resolution.(It would resize appropriately from the biggest image).

If it does not help after that too, then you would need to contact the helpdesk for the app store.

Comment: But which of the 4 options(Pricing and availability, App properties, Packeges, Descriptions and Notes for certification) is the options that allows me to do so. I can't find in none of them the options to update it

Comment: In Descriptions,for each language. you could add the necessary Images. Scroll down to the place below the descriptions and release notes, you would have the AppIcons, preview images, marketing images, search keywords etc. It is independent of the language and you would have to update them separately for each language.